# AmpScript - Output textarea value including breaks

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript

In a DE i have a field called "Description" which includes multiple lines within the description. How ever when i output the variable using AMP Script it removes the line breaks and outputs the info in a single line.

How do I get to display the information with the line breaks in?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: How exactly are the line breaks marked?

Comment: @zuzannamj in the DE they're not marked.

Comment: @MikeWalmsley remember to mark my answer as accepted, if it has been helpful

Answer (score 2):

You can use this Ampscript to replace the newlines in the string stored in your data extension, with actual HTML linebreaks (`<br/>`):

ASCII code explanation: char(13) is carriage return and char(10) is line feed - you want to replace these, as they indeed will not be reflected as HTML linebreaks, only linebreaks in your source code.

```ampscript
%%[
var @dataExtensionText, @printText
set @dataExtensionText = AttributeValue("dataExtensionField")
set @printText = replace(replace(@dataExtensionText ,char(13),""), char(10),"<br/>")
]%%

Original from DE: %%=v(@dataExtensionText)=%%
With linebreaks: %%=v(@printText)=%%
```